# Book like 'Ancestry and Culture' but with a lot more races included

Tags: dnd-5e, races, product-identification

I remember encountering a D&D book online as a pdf, which offered rules to create characters belonging to multiple races/cultures, similar to 'Ancestry and Culture'. Unlike 'Ancestry and Culture', it had a lot more races, including Yuan-ti, goblinoids, and warforged. It also offered multiple options for what set of traits you could get from each parent: one of the options for the tiefling allowed you to add wings. After the race list there was a table of traits with points to allow for 'mixing-and-matching' to create a hybrid of more lineages. The only way I found to view the book was to download it, but now I've lost the drive to which it was saved

Does anyone have any idea of what this book is called, or where to find it?

Answer (score 11):

I have just found a backup of my drive, and have managed to locate this book within my backup: The title is '[An Elf and an Orc Had a Little Baby](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/321845/An-Elf-and-an-Orc-Had-a-Little-Baby-Parentage-and-Upbringing-in-DD)'